# Thread Id remains unchanged even after recompilation

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a very simple java multithreading program which i am running on VSCode editor. I noticed that output of the program remains the same even if i compiles it multiple times. My understanding is that value of thread.getId() should be random values every time I recompile code?

```
public class threadclass implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread odd = new Thread(new threadclass());
        Thread even = new Thread(new threadclass());
        odd.start();
        even.start();
        System.out.println("Thread Running");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println("RunnableJob is being run by " + thread.getName() + " (" + thread.getId() + ")");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
RunnableJob is being run by Thread-1 (14)
RunnableJob is being run by Thread-0 (13)
```

Just to re-confirm that id is not changing I restarted my VSCode application and re-runs the program again. Surprisingly it creates output with the same id's again. I am not sure what I am missing here?

Comment: Nothing in the [documentation of `Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html) says that either the name or the id is random. --- By "*recompiling*" yo mean re-run?

Comment: yes I meant re-run. My main concern in the thread id number remains constant every time i re-run it. shouldn't it get new id values every time in re-run the program?

Comment: No, why should it? Again, referring to the [documentation of `Thread::getId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()): "*Returns the identifier of this Thread. The thread ID is a positive long number generated when this thread was created. The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime. **When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.***"

Comment: "The thread ID is a positive long number generated when this thread was created"- if i re-run the program, from where it picks the same id 13, 14 again? does it store these values anywhere? so if i rerun the program it get re-assigned again.

i ran command : 'java threadclass' multiple times in console as well however output remains the same

Comment: It could, yes. It is an implementation detail. It is only guaranteed that the thread ID of a non-terminated thread is a positive `long` value and that is it unique. Nothing less, nothing more.